# How to remove snippets from intellisense?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

[image]

When using VSCode you get a bunch of unnecessary items when you Ctrl+Space inside of a React component.

Any idea how to remove them?

Comment: Currently, you can't remove items from intellisense suggestions. Your best bet would be to [create a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) and ask for the ability to hide snippets from intellisense.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, done: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4934

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like this is supported now, just add the following to your VS Code settings.

```
{
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none" // or "top", "bottom", "inline", etc.
}
```

See also this question:
[Hide snippets when showing the intellisense to get properties in VsCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703868/hide-snippets-when-showing-the-intellisense-to-get-properties-in-vscode)