# Hide snippets when showing the intellisense to get properties in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to hide all snippets in the CTRL+SPACE list?

If I have place the cursor between two { } in a typescript file the intellisense gets all cluddered with snippets even tho I only want the properties of the object im about to create.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does indeed give you the ability to prevent snippets from being shown in the Quick Suggestions list.

This can be done, by adding the `"editor.snippetSuggestions"` property to your [settings file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userandworkspace), and setting its value to `"none"`.

Example:

```
{
    "editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Also worth noting that if you'd still like to have snippets in the list, you can set the value to "bottom" (instead of "none") to have the snippet suggestions appear _after_ all of the other items in the list.

Comment: I love you man... I chosen "bottom" value in place of "none". Thks